# `from django.conf import settings` is not working

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pycharm

I've changed my manage.py and settings.py and added a wsgi.py file to bring my Django 1.4 project closer to the modern age. This was done primarily because `django_gunicorn` is now deprecated. I'm using Python 2.7.9 and Django 1.4.19 in a PyCharm 4.0.6 development environment.

I also changed my directory structure from flat to nested.

```
/gse
    manage.py
    /gse
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        ...
    /app1
    /app2
```

**manage.py**

```
from os import environ
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gse.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gse.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I installed `django-avatar` a while back, and now after the changes mentioned above it is breaking when I run `manage.py validate`.

I get the following traceback in PyCharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "C:\Users\nu\gse\manage.py", line 23, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\validate.py", line 9, in handle_noargs
self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 266, in validate
num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
self._populate()
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 64, in _populate
self.load_app(app_name, True)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 88, in load_app
models = import_module('.models', app_name)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\avatar\models.py", line 23, in <module>
avatar_storage = get_storage_class(settings.AVATAR_STORAGE)()
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 149, in __init__
self.location = abspathu(self.base_location)
File "C:\Users\nu\gseVirtualEnv\lib\ntpath.py", line 487, in abspath
path = _getfullpathname(path)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I noticed that `from django.conf import settings` is used in `django-avatars` `conf.py` file.  I tested the import statement in my project and discovered that PyCharm doesn't seem to be able to list the expected member variables from the settings class when I type `settings.`. My settings file correctly associated with Django in PyCharm.

Comment: I confess I am no expert but would like to suggest that perhaps adding **__init__.py** file to the directory containing settings.py may be enough to fix your problem. As far as I remember, an **__init__.py** file is required (?) to import a module

Comment: There is some problem the way you have set the value for `AVATAR_STORAGE` in settings file, you have set a `tuple` while `string` is required by the library.

Comment: i do have an __init__.py in the directory I just added it to this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Aamir.

When I looked at settings.py again I saw this:

`MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/'),)`

`AVATAR_STORAGE = MEDIA_ROOT + '\avatars'`

Changing the MEDIA_ROOT assignment line to:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'media').replace('\\','/')`

Fixed it.